# Merge [external-display] and [external-monitor]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

There's

- [external-display](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-display), 121 questions
- [external-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-monitor), 13 questions

As the two are obviously synonyms, and the first one is much more widely used, I suggest to:

- Merge [external-display](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-display) and [external-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-monitor) → [external-display](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-display)
- Create a synonym [external-display](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-display) ← [external-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/external-monitor)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
updating post history, 19 rows affected
updating posts, 15 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 13 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [external-display] and [external-monitor] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym external-monitor -> external-display was approved!
```

Now,

[image: BONUZ!!!]

Comment: Here, have a laser pointer!