# Merge [screen] [display] [monitor] and [resolution] [screen-resolution]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I really think we should merge 2 tags out of these 3:

- [screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen) x 544
- [display](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/display) x 564
- [monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitor) x 1032

because they're too similar. There are even [11 questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/display+screen+monitor) tagged with all of them.

I also think we can merge [resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/resolution) and [screen-resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution) (look at the top questions of [resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/resolution) - they obviously relate to screen resolution.)

I know some might refer to resolution not in a screen, but that's why it would be smarter to merge [screen-resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution) into [resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/resolution). One can also tag with [screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen) [resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/resolution).

Comment: Pro merging `[resolution]` and `[screen-resolution]`.

Comment: As for the rest, it made me wonder why we haven't synonymized and merged `[display]` and `[monitor]` yet. Makes perfect sense. As for `[screen]`, we have to go through that and retag all questions about [`[gnu-screen]`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) before we merge that, otherwise we'll create a mess.

Comment: @slhck Well it's pretty much like [your post here](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3734/138020).

Comment: Also, can we merge `[high-dpi]` into `[dpi]`?

Comment: Yeah. I'll wait what the rest thinks though, wouldn't want to merge right away. Rgd. DPI: Isn't High DPI a certain technology as opposed to the general term DPI? I wouldn't merge those, really.

Comment: @slhck Ah, I didn't know that. nvm then.

Comment: High DPI is the higher DPI settings in Windows (making screen contents lager without giving up on pixels), which presents problems with shoddy software. Related, "HiDPI" is Apple's "retina screen" on the Mac, i.e. 4 physical pixels for every logical one.

Comment: FWIW, `display`'s tag wiki isn't about the device, but generally "displaying things". Also, I'd consider these error code things on motherboards and similar devices to be displays, but not screens or monitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have merged [screen-resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution) into [resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/resolution).

All questions tagged [screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen), which actually relate to [gnu-screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) should now have the correct tag. In my opinion, we can go ahead with the merge.

[screen](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen) and [monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitor) have been merged into [display](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/display) and synonyms were created.

Comment: I think display makes more sense than monitor, since monitor can mean 'monitoring' and/or monitor speakers. I personally think its the least ambigious.

Comment: Agreed with [tag:display] over [tag:monitor] (I think of a CPU temperature monitor now when I hear that word) as being the least ambiguous.